# Stop and resume timer in javascript

Tags: javascript, timer

I want to do a timer in javascript but I don't know how to stop and resume it later.I thought this:When I stop the timer,I save the time remaining and when I resume the timer I pass to it the time that I had saved.But I have some questions:is that a good idea?If I stop the timer when an half second is passed (for example I stop it when it is displayed 5 secons but in function I am in 4,5 seconds),how can I recover that 0,5 second?

Comment: Do you have some code ?

Comment: you need to run interval in secondary timer

Comment: That's a project, not a problem. Please try something, post some code and we'll try to help you.

Comment: The fact is that I don't know how to write this code...I can't understand how to  recover the seconds lost...